# How can set my state once when listening resize event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, debouncing

In my react application, I need to listen resize event of the window, so if window size smaller than X, I will call mobileFunc, if it is larger than X, I will call desktopFunc to render some html with a lot variables. (These variables and arguments get different values for desktopFunc and mobileFunc)

I am listening the event, however, every window's size changes sets my state again and again. I don't want to to do that. I am trying to find a way to set/change my state when necessary and if possible decrease listening resize event (optional). I am open to suggestions with debouncing, shouldComponentUpdate etc. I should find an efficient way.

```
// mobile is false by default in my state.
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.setDeviceType)
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.setDeviceType)
}

setDeviceType() {
    if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
        this.setState({mobile: true})
    } else {
        this.setState({mobile: false})
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.mobile ? this.mobileFunc() : this.desktopFunc()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: use a `debounce`

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give me an example based on my code?

Comment: As an aside, what is the reason for doing this? It is rare that I see a true need for something like this to actually be in JS (although there are definitely use cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested, but I *think* this might work...

```js
// mobile is false by default in my state.
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.setDeviceType)
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.setDeviceType)
}

setDeviceType() {
    const { mobile } = this.state;
    if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
        if(!mobile) {
            this.setState({mobile: true})
        }
    } else {
        if(mobile) {
            this.setState({mobile: false})
        }
    }
}

render() {
    const { mobile } = this.state;
    return(
        <div>
            {mobile ? this.mobileFunc() : this.desktopFunc()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

That `if`/`else` block could be cleaned up some, but you really online to do perform a `setState` if it currently isn't what you'd like.

Comment: this might have weird side effects `setState` is async and the resize event fires really fast, it should be done with an instance variable

Comment: No, I wouldn't use an instance variable (doing so would require a `forceUpdate` or some additional checks). If anything you would want to debounce the resize event as you had mentioned in your original comment. Alternatively, you could use the previous state to do some additional checks (`this.setState((prevState) => { ... });`). The other option I could see would be to remove the event listener -> then `setState` -> use `setState`'s callback to re-enable the event listener. All of this is off the cuff and there are probably pros/cons to each option (or others I'm not thinking of).

Answer (score 1):

You can use debounced function.
For example https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce